# ASP.NET web application: Unable to read DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, dll

I have an ASP.NET application, which has two references added: MapServer and GDAL. These two DLL's uses a bunch of other DLL's, and all of them are in my applications `/bin` directory.

When I run the application on my own PC in Visual Studio 2010 it runs fine. When I upload it to my Windows 2008 server with IIS it throws this exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'gdal_csharp' or one of its dependencies.
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

When running the application through Visual Studio on the server it runs fine.

I've even tried adding the `/bin` directory to the PATH enviroment variable, and restarting the server. No luck though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the DLL is a 32-bit only DLL that you are trying to run in a x64-environment. Can you try to set the app-pool to 32-bit only?

Update: a simple instruction is here: http://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-a-32-bit-application-pool-in-iis7-dedicatedvps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the dll at GAC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you may be missing something from the GAC.

To see whats happening you could try turning on [Fusion Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309346%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), this will enable you to view all of the assembly load failures.

[Back to Basics: Using Fusion Log Viewer to Debug Obscure Loader Errors](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)